# Laravel - Call to undefined method Illuminate\Console\GeneratorCommand::handle

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm new to **Laravel**. and I was trying to create a new CRUD from terminal with this command:

```
$ php artisan panel:crud gallery
```

But, it gave me the following error that i have mention below. I've searched for it on google. but I didn't find anything that could help to solve this.

> [ ServerFireTeam Panel Crud Generator ]
>   [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
>         Call to undefined method Illuminate\Console\GeneratorCommand::handle()

Can anybody put me on the right direction?

Comment: what version of laravel do you have?

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5.4

Comment: https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Console/GeneratorCommand.html the GeneratorCommand class doesn't have a handle function, in the laravelpanel documentation i see you need v5.5

Comment: going to try that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need v5.5 of laravel to run laravelpanel 1.7

for laravelpanel 1.6 (which work with laravel v5.4) you need to register PanelServiceProvider

```
providers' => array(
    Serverfireteam\Panel\PanelServiceProvider::class
)
```

and run

`php artisan panel:install`

for more info visit
http://laravelpanel.com/docs/master/automatic-installation

Comment: I did everything: adding the provider to config/app.php and the install, but the problem was the laravel version...

Comment: no it was the laravelpanel version, you needed 1.6 not 1.7

Comment: I had it... `$ composer require serverfireteam/panel
... Using version ^1.7 for serverfireteam/panel
./composer.json has been updated`